# Corrupted memory issue when deleting allocated memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to store a sparse vector using a bit mask. I allocate a `char*` to represent the bit mask. However, when I `delete []` the mask, I get a memory corruption error. Upon investigation, I'm seeing that it's because I'm freeing memory that I'm not supposed to. This is confusing, since I don't see how this could be the case.

When I run this on my case, it prints out `"ALLOCATED"` and `"DEALLOCATING"` but nothing further.

```
void set_i_bit(char* mask, int i) {
  int field_num = floor(i/8);
  int bit_num = i %8;
  mask[field_num] = (1 << bit_num) | mask[field_num];
}

int write_sparse_with_bitmask(vector<float> arr, ofstream* fout) {
  int mx_sz = arr.size() - 1;
  float tol = 0.5;
  char* mask  = 0;
  for(int i = arr.size() -1; i>=0; i-=1) {
    if (fabs(arr[i]) > tol) break;
    mx_sz = i;
  }
  int sprse_cnt = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<=mx_sz; i+=1) {
    if (fabs(arr[i]) < tol) sprse_cnt++;
  }
  int bitmask_sz = ceil(mx_sz/8);
  if (sprse_cnt*sizeof(int16_t) + sizeof(int16_t) > bitmask_sz) {
    cout<<"ALLOCATED"<<endl;
    mask = new char[bitmask_sz];
    for (int i =0; i<bitmask_sz; i++) mask[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<=mx_sz; i+=1) {
      if (fabs(arr[i]) > coef_tol) {
        set_i_bit(mask, i);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    bitmask_sz = 0;
  }
  uint16_t sz = mx_sz + 1;
  uint16_t bt_msk = bitmask_sz + 1;
  char flag = 0;
  if (bitmask_sz > 0) {
    flag = flag | 1;
  }
  fout->write((char*)&sz, sizeof(uint16_t));
  fout->write((char*)&flag, sizeof(char));
  int w_size = sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(char);
  if (flag & 1) {
    fout->write((char*)&bt_msk, sizeof(uint16_t));
    fout->write(mask, sizeof(char)*bt_msk);
    cout<<"DEALLOCATING"<<endl;
    delete [] mask;
    cout<<"THIS DOESN'T PRINT"<<endl;
    w_size += sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(char)*bt_msk;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<=mx_sz; i+=1) {
    if (fabs(arr[i]) > tol || !(flag & 1)) {
      int16_t vl = arr[i];
      fout->write((char*) &vl, sizeof(int16_t));
      w_size += sizeof(int16_t);
    }
  }
  return w_size;
}
```

Comment: I'm finding this code extremely hard to make sense of. There's no indication as to what it's supposed to do, it has no comments, makes little use of meaningful white space and the variable names are generally unclear. In addition, the code shown is not testable in it's current state. Please read about [MCVE]s and provide one.

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? 2) Please provide [mcve]. 3) Why even allocate the memory manually? What's wrong with `std::vector<char> mask (bitmask_sz);`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Why not `std::vector<bool>`? This would be the one time where it would be exactly the right tool (seeing as the question mimics it).

Comment: *Why* do you use manual memory management in the first place? You ought to be using smart pointers and/or containers. Your code will also leak horribly if exceptions are thrown (also easily solved by using containers and smart pointers).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Oh, that is correct.. Didn't even think of that, due to how often I use it..

Comment: You are acessing the array `bt_msk` off bounds, since bt_mask is too large. But I can't explain why the fout->write function should harm with this wrong parameter.

Comment: A memory usage analyzer like Valgrind may be useful here.

Comment: I see many fundamental problems here. "floor(i/8)", when `i` is an `int`, accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever. And *piece de resistance* is "ceil(mx_sz/8)", with `mx_sz` being also an `int` doesn't actually do what you think it does, and I'm pretty sure relying on this for allocating a memory buffer, and scribbling over it, runs off past the end of the array by one byte and then scribbles all over innocent memory that did not deserve the cruel fate that just befell it. You need to open and read the chapter in your C++ book that explains how integer arithmetic works in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was an integer division problem in `ceil(mx_sz/8)`. Integer division was rounding it down. I just didn't notice it. My hack right now is to just: `ceil(mx_sz/8.)`

Comment: If arr.size() == 1, mx_sz and bitmask_sz will be 0, which makes mask an array of size 0. Then this for loop `for(int i = 0; i<=mx_sz; i+=1)` will call `set_i_bit(mask, i)` with i set to 0. meaning you will deference mask(size 0), which is UB.